# How do you export a tensor flow model as JSON?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I was reading the docs on IOHandler, here: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load

and the code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/615c35c213ea7810f8238b8f8475f9fb78dde501/tfjs-core/src/io

but I don't see anything that would just output JSON.

Does something like this exist already? couldn't find anything on npm, and it seems like these existing IO handlers do much more than (de)serialize JSON.

I've tried a number of experiments with no success

```
model.save({ save: console.log }); // just to see what is passed, didn't work

model.save(new class {
  async save(...args) {
    console.log(args); // errors
  }
});
```

and variants of those. the documentation doesn't actually say how to interact with a custom IO Handler, as far as I can tell.